# Unknown provider: $stateParams when using ui-router's resolve in Typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router

I want to convert an Angular ui-router config file with multiple states and resolves to Typescript.

All works well as long as I don't use $stateParams, when I do I get the `Unknown provider` error. I include `$stateParams` dependency in the `$inject`, the `constructor`, the `.config()` while also at the `resolve` function as shown bellow:

```
interface IMyStateParams extends ng.ui.IStateParamsService {
    parentObjectId: Guid;
}

export class listConfig {
    $inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$stateParams', '$qmcPath'];

    constructor(private $stateProvider: ng.ui.IStateProvider, private $urlRouterProvider: ng.ui.IUrlRouterProvider, private $stateParams: IMyStateParams, private $qmcPath: string) {
        this.init();
    }

    private init(): void {
        this.$stateProvider
            .state('client', {
                url: '/client/:parentObjectId',
                views: {
                    'main': {
                        templateUrl: 'MainDetail/',
                        controller: 'ClientDetailController',
                        controllerAs: 'detailCtrl'
                    }
                },
                resolve: {
                    clientDetailService: 'clientDetailService',
                    client: (clientDetailService, $stateParams) => {
                        return clientDetailService.getClientDetail(this.$stateParams.parentObjectId)
                            .then(function (data) {
                                return data;
                            });
                    },
                    clientWVs: function (clientDetailService) {
                        return clientDetailService.getClientDetailWVs()
                            .then(function (result) {
                                return result;
                            });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

(() => {
    angular
        .module('QMC.Klient.List')
        .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$stateParams', '$qmcPath', // more dependencies
            ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $stateParams, $qmcPath) => {
                return new QMC.Klient.List.listConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $stateParams, $qmcPath);
            }
        ]);
})();
```

What is the proper way to include a dependency like that?

Ps. I also tried `this.$stateParams`, same result.

Comment: Does the `QMC.Klient.List` module add `ui-router` as a dependency?

Comment: Yep, it used to work before I migrated to Typescript.

Comment: The listConfig class doesn't need the injectable array from the way I see you're using it. Since you are doing injection and passing it directly to the class. Unknown provider should only be an issue with the `.config` portion of that code. But since moving to typescript order of things included may have changed, which is why I'm wondering does the module itself list ui-router as a dependency as apposed to some parent module.

Comment: Additionally. If you put this in the typescript playground you'l find the $inject is set at a property of the object until it's being constructed. So if you're trying to use the class directly as an injectable that won't work.

Comment: There are a few ways to implement a config file in Typescript, I haven't had any problem with this way so far, so I don't think it has anything to do with the way the $inject is implemented. The module is initialized in a different file, but contains all necessary dependencies. The resolve dependencies on the other hand can be tricky, that is where I think the problem lies...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing all dependencies of $stateParams, and leave only the parameter in the resolve-function

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your problem is exactly because from what I can see this looks valid. The only issue is that the class defines $inject as a property on the object but this won't be set until the class is constructed.

```
// Correct
function MyObj(a, b, c) {}
MyObj.$inject = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

// Incorrect
function MyObj(a, b, c) {
  this.$inject = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
}
```

You can fix this a number of ways. I'd recommend using a decorator. Mostly because it's awesome.

```
@injectable
export class listConfig {
    constructor(private $stateProvider, private $urlRouterProvider, private $stateParams, private $qmcPath: string) {}
}

function injectable(target) {
    var fnStr = target.toString().replace(/((\/\/.*$)|(\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/))/mg, '');
    var result = fnStr.slice(fnStr.indexOf('(')+1, fnStr.indexOf(')')).match(/([^\s,]+)/g);
    if(result === null) {
        result = [];
    }

    target.$inject = result; 
}
```